# swiftui tabview in two different view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Hello I have made a list view with navigation link in the main view I have a tabview and the linked view when entering in every row I have another tabview

but I have this strange effect in the linked view the two tabview are one over the other

I don't see where I have make the mistake can someone help me?

thanks

````
here the code of the main view
 

    import SwiftUI

struct PlantListView: View {
    private let plantItem : [PlantList] = [
        PlantList(
            docId: "tgrferdthsjasksjdf",
            text: "Text1",
            title: "Title1"),
        PlantList(
            docId: "tgrferdthsjasksjdf",
            text: "Text2",
            title: "Title2"),
        PlantList(
            docId: "tgrferdthsjasksjdf",
            text: "Text3",
            title: "Title3"),
    ]
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
                List(plantItem){ PlantList in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailPlantView(),
                        label: {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text(PlantList.text)
                                .font(.headline)
                                Text(PlantList.title)
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                            }
                        })
        }
                .navigationBarTitle("Your Plant", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}



struct PlantListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            PlantListView()
        }
       
    }
} 

----------------and here the code of the linked view------------------

    import SwiftUI

struct DetailPlantView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Screen Plant Status")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Plant Status")
                }
            Text("Screen Plant Data")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "newspaper")
                    Text("Plant Data")
                }
        }
        .accentColor(Color.MyTheme.yellowColor)
        .navigationBarTitle("test", displayMode: .inline)
    }
    
}

struct DetailPlantView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            DetailPlantView()
        }
        
    }
} ```

[![linked view][1]][1]
[![main view][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2gLD.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/taMv0.png
````

Comment: Am I right to assume that there's another TabView somewhere up the viewstack?

if this is the case, you could use a `fullScreenCover` and put the second TabView in there. This isn't encouraged by Apple though: 
"Don’t hide a tab bar when people navigate to different areas in your app. A tab bar enables global navigation for your app, so it should remain visible everywhere. The exception to this is in modal views. Because a modal view gives people a separate experience that they dismiss when they’re finished, it’s not part of the overall navigation of your app."

Comment: Thanks great explaining